# Recursive descent parser: how to find the FIRST, FOLLOW, and PREDICT sets?

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent

I'm looking for a good explanation of the definitions of the FIRST, FOLLOW, and PREDICT sets of a RDP when given a grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *Programming Language Pragmatics*, by Michael L. Scott (Morgan Kaufmann). Parsing is covered in chapter 2. Recursive-descent parsing is described in section 2.2.3; *first* and *follow* sets in 2.2.5.

Answer (score 2):

You can automatically calculate first, follow, and predict sets using [Calculate Predict, First, and Follow Sets from BNF (Backus Naur Form) Grammar Specification](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/predict-first-follow-set) without having to download anything. It's a good way to verify answers or automate the tedium.

If you want to do it manually, [the Dragon Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811) (2nd ed) covers it on pages 221-222.